# Is anyone else having problems with PayPal sandbox? I get a Message 4003 error page every time I try to use it

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Right. So this is an odd one, but I can't find anywhere suggesting any fixes I can do, and PayPal isn't responding to my support requests.

Last week I updated to the new version of PayPal Developer. This was fine, and I was able to do Sandbox testing with it. Please note that that is the case - it was working.

On Friday, it just stopped working. I have now tried it on four different devices, wiped all the cookies, caches and everything else. I've used a mobile device over cellular connection and Firefox, Chrome and Opera on three different desktops. What I get every time I try and make a payment is the below message. I have done everything it has suggested and more.

This message is displayed after logging into the developer sandbox, and trying to make a payment through a PayPal Payments Standard Encrypted Web Payment Button.

> If you were making a purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30 minutes.
>
> If you came to this page from another website, please return to that site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.
>
> If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your activity. You might have to log in again.
>
> **We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.**
>
> **For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.**
>
> **Message 4003**

This is not the full message, but the full message repeats the bold text in several different languages.

Now, this seems to be a sandbox problem, as my live code is working fine, but I have a project I can't release without testing, and I can't test it. Does anyone have any ideas?

I can accept temporary difficulties, but this has been like this since Friday morning (so 72 hours ago) and I haven't received any response from PayPal on it (despite the 24 hour return they promised).

A better question of course, might be "is anyone else having this problem?"

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. PayPal was most unhelpful in telling me that I'd managed to switch two variables around - hence the problem.

Note to self, and to other developers: if you're having problems sending something to PayPal and you think it should work, try using it without the encryption. PayPal's system was perfectly willing to tell me the problem once I wasn't sending a encrypted data package.

Comment: how did you encrypt the button?

Comment: Using the standard PayPal encryption website payments SDK.

Comment: See https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_encryptedwebpayments#id08A3I0QC0X4